# Clear only the visible data data from Chart

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have this example of javaFX LineChart. I would like to reset the data into the chart.

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    private Timeline timeline2;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> sc;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage)
    {    
        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().add(series);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sc));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        prepareTimeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(50);
                executor.execute(this);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void prepareTimeline()
    {
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                addDataToSeries();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty())
                break;
            series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove()));
        }

        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to implement this?

I suppose that I have to clear the chart's buffer but I can't find proper solution.

I tested to use `sc.getData().clear();` but this code clears all data. I would like to clear only the visible data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I would like to clear only the visible data.'. You have MAX_DATA_POINTS size data in series, so all of them are visible i believe... If you want to keep data in chart you probably should not use `series.getData().remove(` in addDataToSeries

Comment: For example when I choose clear from context menu I like to clear the data without stopping or rebooting the Thread. I just want to clear the data into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a flag to indicate that you wish to clear data. In the thread you either update the data depending on that flag or you clear them.

Quick example with a "Clear" button and the mentioned flag:

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    private Timeline timeline2;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> sc;
    private boolean clearFlag = false;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage)
    {    
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().add(series);

        bp.setCenter(sc);

        HBox toolbar = new HBox();
        Button clearButton = new Button( "Clear");
        clearButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            clearFlag = true;
        });
        toolbar.getChildren().add( clearButton);

        bp.setTop(toolbar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        prepareTimeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(50);
                executor.execute(this);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
//                Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void prepareTimeline()
    {
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                if( clearFlag) {
                    clearChart();
                    clearFlag = false;
                } else {
                    addDataToSeries();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void clearChart() {
        dataQ.clear();
        series.getData().clear();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty())
                break;
            series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove()));
        }

        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    }
}
```

And if you only want to clear a selected range of data, simply modify clearChart() and delete that range from dataQ instead of all data, then let the normal chart filling progress.